# rollup Error: Unexpected token (Note that you need plugins to import files that are not JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, rollupjs, rollup-plugin-postcss

The `rollup` was working normally before the last update, now I don't know what the problem is, `rollup-blugin-postcss` is not working anymore.

---

This is the content of my `rollup.config.js` file:

```
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss'


export default {
    input : 'index.js',
    output : {
        file: 'dist/bundle.js',
        format: 'esm'
    },
    blugins : [
        postcss()
    ]
}
```

---

This is the content of my `index.js` file:

```
import './style.css'

consol.log('test')
```

---

This is the content of my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "tes",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c rollup.config.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "rollup": "^2.60.1",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: `blug-in` is correct?

Comment: I found the solution, thank you, the problem is that I was writing blugins instead of plugins